# .htaccess to shorten current url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Right now I have direction to:

```
www.website.com/user.php?u=peter
```

or

```
www.website.com/userhome.php?u=peter
```

I want to shorten them to

```
www.website.com/user/peter
www.website.com/userhome/peter
```

This is the code I have now, and its not working. When I type website.com/user/peter the website gives me an my own error, as if it isn't able to GET the username. "That user does not exist or is not yet activated, press back"

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on

# NC make the rule non case sensitive
# L make this the last rule that this specific condition will match
# $ in the regular expression makes the matching stop

# Rewrite for user.php?u=xxxxx
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) user.php?u=$1 [NC,L]

# Rewrite for userhome.php?u=xxxxx
RewriteRule ^userhome/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) userhome.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: You have the same rule twice, are you always going to `user.php`? Describe `its not working`. Second rule should be `^userhome/` or maybe even 1 rule `RewriteRule ^user(home)?/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) user$1.php?u=$2 [NC,L]`

Comment: Should that question mark be there in the code you suggested? after (home)

Comment: If you plan on doing it in one rule yes, that makes the `home` optional.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following rules:

```
#To leave the URL www.example.com/user/peter
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)$ /user.php?u=$1 [L]

#To leave the URL www.example.com/userhome/peter
RewriteRule ^userhome/([^/]*)$ /userhome.php?u=$1 [L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing these.